# how to convert from 8-bit to 4-bit by using python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, bitmap

I need to convert the image to 4-bit for the GLCM method. Opencv and similar libraries have a minimum of 8 bits. What should I do? Do you have conversion formulas?

With opencv for 16-bit to 8-bit:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
imagePath = "--"
img_8bit = cv2.imread(imagePath).astype(np.uint8)
```

No conversion to 4 bits in Opencv.

With skimage for example:

```
import cv2
from skimage import exposure
from skimage import img_as_ubyte
src = cv2.imread("cicek.png",0)
print("type: ",src.dtype,"min: ", src.min(),"max: ", src.max(),"size: ",src.shape)
img = exposure.rescale_intensity(src, in_range=(0,15))
```

The above code did not work.

Comment: I am not familiar with GLCM, I don't understand why you might want 4-bit bitmap (it's only useful to save a bit of space on old computers, by storing 2 pixels in a single byte). Anyway, on Windows you can use WinAPI functions. There must be other libs that can do that. Otherwise reduce the 256 color palette to 16 colors (I don't know which of the colors you want to pick, and on what criteria) then manually create the 4-bit bitmap file.

Comment: So, you want each pixel stored as byte, but only use range 0..15? Or, do you actually want to pack pairs of pixels into a single byte? Please, elaborate.